# bash, logic of: a && b && c

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, logic

One thing I don't get with this operators is when I use two of them in sequence.

What I mean by that:

```
% true && echo "problem" 
problem

% echo $?
0
```

So far, so good. `true` returns "error" (exit status 1) and `echo "problem"` returns 0, so logical AND operation result must be 0.

```
% true && echo "problem" || echo "exit"
problem
```

OK, that's a surprise: since `true && echo "problem"` results in 0, `||` should also evaluate `echo "exit"`, since after all right-hand operand of `||` might be true and so the result of this logical OR might be true.

Now:

```
% true && echo "problem" && echo "exit"
problem
exit
```

This is also surprising: after all since `true && echo "problem"` returns zero, the lazy `&&` operator should *not* evaluate `echo "exit"` since the result of logical AND must be zero anyway.

Why is the behavior of last two examples opposite to what I intuitively expect?

P.S. This is opposite of Python behavior:

```
% python
>>> def pp():
...     print "problem"
... 

>>> def pe():
...     print "exit"

>>> True and pp() and pe()
problem

>>> True and pp() or pe()
problem
exit
```

Comment: Your assumption is wrong: true returns "0". that is the "clear" condition for the shell. "&&" let execute the next command if the current one has returned correctly, that is $? value is 0. Try replacing "echo problem" with "false", that actually returns 1: the chained commands stop.

Comment: Remember that bash's boolean values are the opposite of most programming languages like C and Python. In `bash`, 0 is truthy, non-zero is falsey.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're misunderstanding success/failure statuses and also what `&&` and `||` mean in this context in bash.

An exit status of success is `0`, while failure is non-zero so when you say `true returns "error" (exit status 1)`, no it doesn't. Also, nothing in shell "returns" anything. Scripts and functions produce output and have an exit status - using the word "return" leads to confusion over which of those 2 separate things you mean. For example if we define this function:

```
foo() {
    echo "hello"
    return 7
}
```

and then use it to populate a variable:

```
var=$(foo)
$ echo "$var"
hello
```

did `foo()` "return" `hello` or did `foo()` "return" 7? The best answer is no, it didn't "return" either - it output `hello` and exited with status `7`.

Although there's a poorly-named "return" keyword there what that REALLY is producing is an exit status for the function, the same as if you had a shell script that was just:

```
echo "hello"
exit 7
```

and you can see that if you test it (`$?` always holds the exit status of the most recently run command):

```
foo() {
    echo "hello"
    return 7
}

$ foo
hello

$ echo "$?"
7
```

I assume the shell creators chose "return" for the function keyword because "exit" already meant "exit from the running process" but IMHO that made things confusing, though I don't have a better suggestion and even if I did that ship has sailed long ago. If you read `return 7` as `set the exit status to 7 then return from the function` without assuming the function is actually "returning" anything then you'd be right.

Note also that the function is outputting "hello" - that's also not a "return" but if you use it as `var=$(foo)` then `var` ends up containing `hello` so then some people incorrectly refer to that as a "return" too since in other languages like C if you wrote `var=foo()`:

```
char *foo() {
    return "hello"
}
var=foo()
```

then `var` would contain the argument that was given to `return` in the function but that is just not the same semantics as shell where, unlike the similar C code above, `var=$(foo)` sets `var` to the **output** from `foo()`, not the "return" (actually exit status) from `foo()`.

So - the function above doesn't actually "return" anything, it outputs `hello` and exits with status `7`.

So here's what your command line `true && echo "problem" || echo "exit"` actually does:

- `true` = output nothing and exit with status 0 (success)
- `echo "problem"` - output `problem` and exit with status 0 (success)
- `echo "exit"` - output `exit` and exit with status 0 (success)

Now, what do `&&` and `||` mean? What they really are is shorthand for `if` statements:

- `&& foo` = if the previously run command exited success then execute `foo`
- `|| foo` = if the previously run command exited failure then execute `foo`

So a command line like:

```
cmdA && cmdB || cmdC
```

in terms of success/fail status should be read as:

```
cmdA
ret=$?
if (( ret == 0 )); then
    cmdB
    ret=$?
fi
if (( ret != 0 )); then
    cmdC
    ret=$?
fi
( exit "$ret" )
```

We need the `ret` temp variable because the `if` itself has an exit status that'd overwrite `$?`. So `cmdC` will get called if `cmdA` exits with a failure status, but it'll also get called if `cmdA` succeeded and then `cmdB` exited with a failure status. At the end of `cmdA && cmdB || cmdC` the exit status as stored in `$?` will simply be the exit status of whichever command ran last, it will not, for example, be the product of boolean arithmetic on all of the exit statuses of all the commands that ran as apparently suggested in the question might be the case.

Note also that what that should NOT be read as is what you may intuitively have expected if you thought of `&& ... || ...` as a ternary expression, which trips many people up, especially since that `||` is typically an error leg whose incorrect placement may escape your code inspectors/testers notice:

```
cmdA
if (( $? == 0 )); then
    cmdB
else
    cmdC
fi
```

Given  the above, here's what your command lines actually mean:

1. `true && echo "problem" || echo "exit"`

```
true
ret=$?
if (( ret == 0 )); then
    echo "problem"
    ret=$?
fi
if (( ret != 0 )); then
    echo "exit"
    ret=$?
fi
( exit "$ret" )
```

2. `true && echo "problem" && echo "exit"`

```
true
ret=$?
if (( ret == 0 )); then
    echo "problem"
    ret=$?
fi
if (( ret == 0 )); then
    echo "exit"
    ret=$?
fi
( exit "$ret" )
```

and if what you WANTED to have happen instead of "2" above was actually:

```
true
if (( $? == 0 )); then
    echo "problem"
else
    echo "exit"
fi
```

then you should write that code or similar instead of using `&&`s and `||`s  (e.g. as 1 line you could write `if true; then echo "problem"; else echo "exit"; fi`) so you don't get unexpected output if you reach the `echo "problem"` leg and it fails for some reason thereby causing you to afterwards fall into the `echo "exit"` leg (unlikely with just `echo` but very possible with other commands).

Comment: In this snippet `true
if (( $? == 0 )); then
    echo "problem"
fi
if (( $? != 0 )); then
    echo "exit"
fi`, if you replace `true` by `false`, nothing prints.

Comment: @Philippe yeah, you're right, I forgot the `if` itself would reset `$?`. I'll fix my answer.

Comment: @Philippe I think I cleared it up but don;t have time to really think it through right now so if you spot any other issues please let me know and I'll look at it again later.

Comment: Perfect now, apart from last statement : `(( ret == 0 ))`. To be exactly equivalent, maybe `(exit $ret)`.

Comment: @Philippe yeah, you're right , I hate that this complexity of a separate variable name and now a sub-process has had to creep in as it kinda obscures the main point if the comparison but I guess it's got to be accurate so I made the changes.

Comment: @EdMorton hmm re "echo "exit" - output exit and exit with status 0 (success)" - "exit" is not printed (on "true && echo "problem" || echo "exit"). I think it's because 'true && echo "problem"' exits with status 0 (success) so || does not need to evaluate second command? The bullet list there seems may be interpreted in a way that suggests all of those three items actually execute.

Comment: That is not what that bullet list states.